# Is there in spring mvc abstractions over HttpServletResponse?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlets, model, httpresponse

When I use spring mvc I don't use raw `HttpServletRequest`. Instead of this I use `Model`.

Is there similar way to avoid using `HttpServletResponse` ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I get your question.

Spring MVC is deriving the HttpServletResponse from whatever your controller method returns, and exception handlers (if a business exception was thrown by that method), interceptors, HttpMessageConverters, etc. Maybe half of the Spring MVC reference documentation deals with that.

Maybe looking at the [supported method return types in Controllers](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-return-types) will answer your question?

Also, your Controller method can return a `ResponseEntity<?>` type, which you can use like this:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

  @RequestMapping("/test")
  public ResponseEntity<String> test() {
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).header("X-Foo", "Bar").body("Hello World!");
  }

  @RequestMapping(value= "/other", produces = "application/json")
  public ResponseEntity<User> other() {
    User user = new User("firstName", "lastName");
    // here, Spring MVC will use a configured HttpMessageConverter to convert your model
    // instance to JSON, for example
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(user);
  }
}
```